# Linear Algebra - Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need some help with vector spaces.

basically what I need to do is express this:

$$\frac{1}{3+ 5(7)^\frac{1}{3} + 4 (7)^\frac{2}{3}}$$

and express that to this:

$$ x + y\times7^\frac{1}{3} + z\times7^\frac{2}{3}$$

This is what I got:

$$1= (3+ 5(7)^\frac{1}{3} + 4(7)^\frac{2}{3})(x + y\times7^\frac{1}{3} + z\times7^\frac{2}{3})$$

I'm just suppose to have three different equations.

Basically I think I have to expand, I'm not sure what to do here. My teacher did a example in class but it was very hard to follow, any help will be helpful!

Also, if anyone could tell me the name of what this is, it would be helpful. I know it's vector space but like specifically what is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing your last equation like this: $$1=3(x+y\cdot7^{\frac{1}{3}}+z\cdot7^{\frac{2}{3}})+(5\cdot 7^{\frac{1}{3}})(x+y\cdot7^{\frac{1}{3}}+z\cdot7^{\frac{2}{3}})+(4\cdot 7^{\frac{2}{3}})(x+y\cdot7^{\frac{1}{3}}+z\cdot7^{\frac{2}{3}})$$

Then we get $$1=3x+3y\cdot7^{\frac{1}{3}}+3z\cdot7^{\frac{2}{3}}+(5\cdot 7^{\frac{1}{3}})x+(5\cdot 7^{\frac{1}{3}})y\cdot7^{\frac{1}{3}}+(5\cdot 7^{\frac{1}{3}})z\cdot7^{\frac{2}{3}}+(4\cdot 7^{\frac{2}{3}})x+(4\cdot 7^{\frac{2}{3}})y\cdot7^{\frac{1}{3}}+(4\cdot 7^{\frac{2}{3}})z\cdot7^{\frac{2}{3}}$$ which becomes, when we group like terms:

$$1=(3x+5z+4y)+(3y+5x)\cdot 7^{\frac{1}{3}}+(3z+5y+4x)\cdot 7^{\frac{2}{3}}+(4z)\cdot 7^{\frac{4}{3}}$$  Finally, since $7^{\frac{4}{3}}=7\cdot 7^{\frac{1}{3}}$, we finish off the equation as $$1=(3x+5z+4y)+(3y+5x+28z)\cdot 7^{\frac{1}{3}}+(3z+5y+4x)\cdot 7^{\frac{2}{3}}$$

So, if $s+t\cdot 7^{\frac{1}{3}}+u\cdot 7^{\frac{2}{3}}$ was the intended form for your final expression, you can take $$s=3x+5z+4y$$ $$t=3y+5x+28z$$ $$u=3z+5y+4x$$

Comment: When use the expansion, I get decimals, when my teacher did it he got whole numbers and btw is 1/3 and 2/3 not 13 and 23

Comment: You don't need to go to the decimal level.  Just use the distributive property and group like terms, etc.

Comment: Sorry about the 13 and 23.  That was a formatting error.  Fixed.

Comment: I'm still not getting it, when my teacher did it he got three different equations

Comment: I dont get how did you get (3x + 5z + 4y), why did you go from x to z then to y

Comment: Do you know what it means to 'group like terms'?  Therein lies the key.